# How can I check whether a website has javascript or not?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm building a webscraper using beautifulsoup.Some websites have javascript contents and do not load using urllib3 hence I use selenium for them.But selenium takes too long too respond and I need to build a more efficient webscraper since I need to use the same generalized scraper for multiple websites. hence I'm thinking if there's some way I can find out if the website has js content only then ill use selenium else I'll go with faster urllib

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

browser = webdriver.Chrome()

strt=time.time()
y=browser.get("https://www.amazon.jobs/en/locations/bangalore-india")
#time.sleep(10)
html = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
li=soup.find_all('ul')
print(li)
print('load time='+str(time.time()-strt))
```

Comment: 95% of all sites use JavaScript - https://w3techs.com/technologies/details/cp-javascript/all/all

Comment: You can use scrapy with splash requests to render JS

Comment: FYI, I checked the webpage you're trying to scrape, It contains JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the simple check using selenium

```
jsSize = (len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/head/script")))

if jsSize>0:
    print("Page contains javascript")
```

Answer (score 1):

The **script** tag is used to define a client-side script (JavaScript).

The  element either contains script statements, or it points to an external script file through the src attribute.

Right click on the webpage you want to scrape >> Go to View Page Source >>

look for the tag named **script**, the script tag will indicate that the web page you are trying to scrape also consist of JavaScript.

Comment: yes but I want it to choose from selenium or urllib by itself and to find script tag i need html markup which i would only get from urllib or selenium